# How long can I store pork shoulder in the fridge if cooked with high content of salt

Tags: storage-lifetime, ham

I cook usually 1kg block at 65°C for 6 hours with 40g (4%) of salt, 10g (1%) of sugar, and a good amount of white and black pepper.

After cooking it, I cool it in an ice bath, then I store it in the fridge; first, one day uncovered, so it dries out a bit, and then in a Tupperware.

It tastes like ham, and I slice it for my breakfast sandwiches.

My question is, for how long would it be safe to keep it? I tried it up to 6 days after, and I don't feel any change in the taste or the texture, but I don't know if I am pushing the limits. On the other hand, I guess that the high content in salt may help to preserve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer/21069)

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is a very basic question and I suggest that you read the tag info on food-safety and the questions linked from it. Also, for the subquestion about the salt: It doesn't matter. If you have not followed a known, tested preservation process to the letter (and "just throw in some salt" is not a process), your food falls into the same category as any other perishable food.